# Fazer toast desaparecer ao correr comando root

Tags: android, shell, time

Viva,

Tenho o telemóvel ligado ao computador e quando corro comandos root pelo adb, aparece sempre uma toast no êcra, existe alguma forma de fazer estas toats desaparecerem? Relembro que elas não estão a ser criadas pelo meu código.

Já tentei correr este comando no ínicio, mas não deu em nada :S

```
su appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny //adb shell
```

[image: toast_que_tem_de_desaparecer]

Comment: você tem alguma aplicação de superuser instalada no smartphone ?

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro sim, o superSU

Comment: Vai nas configurações, marca para garantir sempre a permissão e tem uma configuração lá para não mostrar mais o alerta de quando garantir

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro it worked, if you want to anwser that bellow i give you the correct anwser, thanks ;)

Comment: glad to help, i've put as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai nas configurações, marca para garantir sempre a permissão e tem uma configuração lá para não mostrar mais o alerta de quando garantir.